# I want to convert the points in the drawing to the corresponding model space

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge, viewer

There is a feature in the acc viewer that allows you to jump to the corresponding position in the model by selecting a point and direction on the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaiKH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epD1A.png)

This seems to involve a method of converting the points on the drawing to the model space, and I have tried many times, such as focusing the model through dbid, but I have not achieved this effect.

```
 let viewer = this.viewer;
    if (param) {
      viewer.clearSelection()
      viewer.isolate(param.dbIdArray)
      viewer.fitToView(param.dbIdArray)
    }
    this.viewer.addEventListener(window.Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function(selected) {
      console.log(selected)
      viewer.selectedDbIdArray = selected.dbIdArray;
      viewer.model.getProperties(selected.dbIdArray[0], function(props) {
        console.log(props)
      });
    });
```

Is there anyone who can help me.

Comment: There is this great article that explains how to map 2D coordinates to 3D view using AEC metadata : [Mapping between sheets and 3D views AEC models](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/mapping-between-sheets-and-3d-views-aec-models)